# Microsoft UI Automation not returning expected ComboBox items

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to get the listitems of a combobox using the following UI AUtomation code and zero items are being returned. There certainly are items in this comobbox so what am I doing wrong?

```
var comboBox = GetMarketAreasComboBox();
var items = comboBox.FindAll(TreeScope.Element, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
```

Where GetMarketAreasComboBox is defined as:

```
private AutomationElement GetMarketAreasComboBox()
{
    var control = LocalRootAutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants , new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "MarketAreasComboBox"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(control);
    return control;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the list item elements have not yet loaded into memory.  Expand the ComboBox, and then check for the ListItem elements

```
var comboBox = GetMarketAreasComboBox();
var comboBoxPattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)comboBox.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern);
comboBoxPattern.Expand();
comboBoxPattern.Collapse();
var items = comboBox.FindAll(TreeScope.Element, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things that I would have tried 
1. Check if combo box is not null
2. Change scope to descendants for comboBox.FindAll.
3.Make sure I am hitting the code path when the list items are actually loaded under combo box (May be expand require as suggested by jvanbrakel above)